# Cannot boot windows after HDD change

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, sata, pata

I got PC with MSI n1996 motherboard and a SATA HDD. My HDD broke down so I had to change it. I changed it with a PATA HDD. After I installed it to pc, wanted to start it. It didn't boot the win10 that was installed to it.
In the motherboard's bios I can see the HDD.

I removed the HDD and installed a win8 in another machine to it. After I put the HDD back to the pc it still wanted to boot win10.

Do you have any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

If EFI = EFI Boot error, Set first boot to efi[Disk] instead of [Windows Boot Manager]

- Go into bios
- Find "Boot" device settings. (bioses are different)
- Basicaly locate things that are Boot from Disk order
- Set device First to PATA... (insert disk here)
- If EFI: Then it should have a word-list like "Windows Boot Manager" or whatnot...

The reason why it still looks for win 10 is because EFI stuff is saved... somewhere else.

- Details...

### Functionally speaking, theres 2 ways to boot windows.

- bios
- efi

Bios is "The Computer finds hardware, sets them up, and then boots.

EFI is... "Windows/whatever boots up a bit, then drivers set things up."

Comment: Hey, what does this exactly means?

Comment: Added some details - Im not the best at directions.